# TV mount in plaster wall with no studs

Tags: safety, structural

Is it possible to mount a 65in tv on a 1.5in thick plaster wall over a fireplace? there are no studs, and about a 3in air space before its solid again. probably insde brick chimney wall. i never use the fireplace

Comment: I would want to add some structure, what is holding the plaster in place?

Comment: As @EdBeal states, old plaster is weak. It was likely reinforced with horsehair and lathe, and probably barely supports its own weight. Use a floor or ceiling support that hides the cables; it would look better, too.